# Telerik MVC Grid edit mode error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I have a form to enter employee's details. In that i am entering employee contact details and address details. For address i am using MVC grid to CRUD operations. I selected the editing mode as "GridEditMode.InLine". There is no javascript error in page loading, clicking add new row button of the grid. When i get focus any of the editable fields in the row i am getting the following error

"jquery.validate.min.js:19Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined"

How can i rectify this problem?

Note: I am using Telerik extensions 2011.2.712. The address grid is in partial view, so that i can use to vendor & customer address too. Also i am using EF in data layer.

Thanks & Regards
Kousik

Comment: you have to post some code here to more understand your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The Telerik controls require the proper scripts to be registered or included in the page.  They recommend using their script registrar to do this (something like the following).

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group
                .Add("jquery-1.5.1.min.js")
                .Add("jquery.validate.min.js ")
                .Add(<any additional scripts>))
)
```

You can do this manually the "old" way, but their API is much easier, plus it gives you the benefit of being able to compress and combine all scripts into one file through the API to reduce footprint.

You can refer to http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-required-javascript-files.html for more detailed information on which scripts are needed for specific controls.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Telerik adds references to the jQuery version included in its package. If you are manually adding a jQuery reference in your Site.Master/_Layout (ASPX/RAZOR respectively), you should also modify the Telerik ScriptRegister to exclude automatic jQuery referencing with `.jQuery(false)`.

Sample unmodified Telerik script registrar-

```
<%: Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)) %>
```

With automatic-jQuery referencing disabled-

```
<%: Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)) %>
```

If you don't do this, there a conflict by arise over which reference is used to run an operation, especially if your Telerik controls are using a different jQuery version.